# how to make future dates should not appear or disable only for the current year,in date time select in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

i am using rails date time select. with start year and end year options. and here a user should be able to select all dates from the last year to till the current date. a user should not be allowed to select future dates for the current year. how can i do this? if i menction start date and end date options will that restrict the dates for the previous year also?

```
<%= f.datetime_select :check_out_req, { start_year: Date.today.year - 1,:end_year => Date.today.year,ampm: true, order: [:day, :month, :year] }, { class: "form-control" }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `<select>`s that `datetime_select` generates are static, so they can't disable options depending on other selections. Eg, Rails won't disable Sept 2015 without Sept also being disabled for 2014.

You have a few options to get what you want:

- Validate the date on your model. Check that it's within `1.year.ago.to_date..Date.today`, and display a typical validation error to the user if it's not.
- Implement some JavaScript on the frontend that enables and disables month and day selectors as year and month are selected.
- Pick a JS plugin that will help you. There are lots around:

  - [Pikaday](https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday)
  - [jQuery UI Datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)
  - [Datepicker for Bootstrap](https://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker)